# Is it correct to assume that the Startup class is only ever used once per boot of a server

Tags: asp.net, owin

Does the startup class of a ASP.NET website run once per server boot, or does it timeout and then re-create after a certain timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

The startup class will be executed once each time you call *WebApp.Start()* (or equivalent). The server won't timeout or go idle and have to restart itself.

You can however re-run WebApp.Start without closing the program, or run it multiple times simultaneously. The only limitation is that you cannot have 2 instances of WebApp running on the same port at the same time.